# Publishing Facebook Action through new graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm simply trying to post an action to Facebook using the iOS SDK / new graph.

> Problem is I keep getting an alert saying 'Action Requires at Least
>   One Reference' It's invalid because it does not specify any reference
>   objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified:
>   event, friend, favorite, reminder.

Here is my current code:

```
    FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
   NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *course = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
    course[@"og:title"] = @"My Event";
    course[@"og:type"] = @"myEventApp:event";
    course[@"og:url"] = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
    course[@"og:description"]  = @"Yaba daba doo";
    action[@"course"] = course;

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/myEventApp:add" parameters:action tokenString:token.tokenString version:@"v2.3" HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                if(error)
                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                else
                                    NSLog(@"%@", result);

                            }];

    [connection start];
```

Comment: An action doesn't have an og:url. An object does, and an action needs to reference an object. You should change the action[@"og:url"] to be action[@"{my_object_type}"] instead, replacing {my_object_type} with an object that can go into your action.

Comment: Updated my code, now I get no UIAlertView error, but rather this error:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x170866400 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x1706457f0 "unsupported URL"}


Also tried course[@"og:url"] = @"http://www.facebook.com"

Comment: Also noticed FBSDKLog: Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment:{
    data =     {
    };
    "fbsdk:create_object" = 1;
    "og:description" = "Yaba daba doo";
    "og:image" = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png";
    "og:title" = "My Event";
    "og:type" = "myEventApp:event";
    "og:url" = "http://www.facebook.com";
}, skipping.

Comment: well, facebook.com is not a valid url for that og object.

Answer (score 1):

Posting Data:
You should add permission @"publish_actions"

Try this code:

```
 if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
        // TODO: publish content.
        NSLog(@"published...");
    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            //TODO: process error or result.
        }];
    }
```